# Footnotes and Endnotes

Tags: plugins, richtext

Are there any plugins or best practices for giving authors in Craft the ability to create footnotes within a Rich Text Field? Is anyone doing anything like this?

Comment: I have a footnotes plugin in the works that I could share for beta testing really soon, Jonathan.

Comment: @carlcs That would be great. I'd be happy to provide feedback for you on your plugin.

Comment: Jonathan, contact me on craft slack and I will send you a copy. Sorry that it took longer than expected, but I did another refactor and added new features.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a solution for footnotes within Rich Text fields aside from the plugin referenced in the comments of the question. As an alternative, consider having a read over [Craft Your Content With Markdown And Matrix](https://experiencehq.net/blog/craft-with-markdown-and-matrix) by Stephen Lewis.  He explains how he handles footnotes using Matrix and smartdown.

Answer (score 1):

Next to [carlcs' plugin](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-footnotes) (which is still in private beta apparently) there's also [Craft Footnotes](https://github.com/Vierbeuter/craft-footnotes).